# get unique combination of values of two columns

Tags: shell, cut

I can get the unique values from col using below command

```
cut -d',' -f3 file.txt | uniq -c.
```

This gives me unique values in field 3.

But if I want to get unique combination of two fields, how can I get that ?

input

```
A,B,C
B,C,D
D,B,C
H,C,D
K,C,D
```

output

```
2 B,C
3 C,D
```

Comment: pre-process using another command to concatenate columns 2 + 3 then pipe the results of that through cut and uniq (the exact commands you have now).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify range of fields using `-f 2-3` or `-f 2,3`

```
cut -d',' -f2-3 file.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

`uniq` does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent. Input should be sorted before using uniq command

Output

```
2 B,C
3 C,D
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you may find provides greater flexibility in processing the input is `awk`. You can use a concatenation of the fields at issue as an index for an array to sum the occurrences of each unique combination of fields and then output the results using the `END` rule, e.g.

```
awk -F, '{a[$2","$3]++} END{for(i in a)print a[i], i}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example file in `input` you would have:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$2","$3]++} END{for(i in a)print a[i], i}' input
3 C,D
2 B,C
```

`awk` arrays are associative rather than indexed, but you can preserve the order of appearance using a 3rd array if needed. Or you can simply pipe the output to `sort` for whatever order you like.